# railscast 197 how to: function add_fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, railscasts

I am following the railscast 197 but I'm using rails 3.1.3,jQuery and scaffold, no nifty:scaffold,everything works fine but I can't add fields, in that episode Ryan Bates give the code for jQuery, but is not working for me, here is my code:

in **javascript/application.js**

```
function remove_fields(link) {  
    $(link).prev("input[type=hidden]").val("1");  
    $(link).closest(".fields").hide();  
  }  

function add_fields(link, association, content) {  
    var new_id = new Date().getTime();  
    var regexp = new RegExp("new_" + association, "g");  
    $(link).parent().before(content.replace(regexp, new_id));  
}
```

**helper/application_helper.rb**

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_remove_fields(name, f)  
    f.hidden_field(:_destroy) + link_to_function(name, "remove_fields(this)")  
  end  

  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)  
  new_object = f.object.class.reflect_on_association(association).klass.new  
  fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, :child_index => "new_#{association}") do |builder|  
    render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", :f => builder)  
  end  
  link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#{escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))  
end    
end
```

**_questions_fields.html.rb**

```
<div class="fields">  
  <p>  
    <%= f.label :content, "Pregunta" %>  
    <%= link_to_remove_fields "remover", f%><br />  
    <%= f.text_area :content, :rows => 3 %><br />  
  </p>  
  <p>
  <% f.fields_for :answers do |builder| %>  
    <%= render 'answer_fields', :f => builder %>  
  <% end %>  
  </p>
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Agregar respuesta", f, :answers %></p> 
</div>
```

**_form.html.rb**

```
<%= form_for @asurvey do |f| %>    

    <%= f.label :name, "Nombre de encuesta" %><br />
    <%= f.text_field :name %>
  </p>
  <%= f.fields_for :questions do |builder| %> 
  <%= render 'question_fields', :f => builder %>
  <% end %>  
  <p><%= link_to_add_fields "Agregar pregunta", f, :questions %>
  <p><%= f.submit "Crear" %></p>  
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution...here in stackoverflow this is:

```
link_to_function(name, h("add_fields(this, \"#{association}\", \"#escape_javascript(fields)}\")"))
```

My ex:

```
link_to_function(name, ("add_fields(this, #{association}', #{escape_javascript(fields)}')"))
```

of course this code in helpers/application_helper.rb

Yes, that is. Now it works. Thanks.