# Nested Model Forms - Railscast #196 revised - Adding fields via jQuery not working

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, nested-forms, railscasts

I was following the [Railscast #196 revised](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-revised) and everything went basically fine, but I am not able to add new fields to the nested form. The "remove fields" function works nicely, but after click on "link_to_add_fields", the browser jumps to the top of the page, and no new field appears.

There are already a ton of questions to this railscast, like [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9085866/railscast-197-how-to-function-add-fields) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505267/problems-adding-fields-in-nested-form-through-jquery-form-railscasts-episode), and I tried to read all of them, but most of them are referring to the original casts from 2010.
I am stuck for hours now, and I can't figure out, where my problem is. Sorry, if its a rookie mistake, I am quite new to rails.
Any help would be really appreciated!

I was following the #196 revised version, using Rails 3.2.13, Ruby 1.9.3

models/post.rb

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
    attr_accessible :content, :title, :image, :postfiles_attributes
    has_many :postfiles, :dependent => :destroy 
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :postfiles, allow_destroy: true
end
```

models/postfile.rb

```
class Postfile < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :dropbox, :gdrive, :post_id
  belongs_to :post
end
```

views/posts/_form.html.erb

```
<%= simple_form_for @post do |f| %>

  <%= f.fields_for :postfiles do |builder| %>
       <%= render 'postfile_fields', f: builder %>
  <% end %>
  <%= link_to_add_fields "Add File", f, :postfiles %>

<% end %>
```

views/posts/_postfile_fields.html.erb

```
<fieldset>  
    <%= f.text_field :dropbox %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
    <%= link_to "remove", '#', class: "remove_fields" %>
</fieldset>
```

postfiles.js.coffee

```
jQuery ->
   $('form').on 'click', '.remove_fields', (event) ->
    $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
    $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
    event.preventDefault()

  $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
    time = new Date().getTime()
    regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
    $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
    event.preventDefault()
```

application_helper.rb

```
module ApplicationHelper
  def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
    new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
    id = new_object.object_id
    fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
      render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
    end
    link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
  end
end
```

Upfront, thank you so much for your help!

UPDATE: I am using simple-form. See the _form file above. Could this be an issue?

UPDATE II:

I get an Javascript error, not sure if this could be an issue for the problem here:
Chrome calls it "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word " and Firebug calls it "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal".
The error points to this js code part:

```
loadData: function(data){

   this.$editor.addClass('st-block__editor');

   this.$editor.html("
   <div class='st-block__inner'>
      <div class='media'>
        <a class='pull-left' >
          <img class='media-object link-pic' src='" + data.thumbnail_url + "'>
        </a>
        <div class='media-body'>
          <div class='link-source'>" + data.provider_name + "</div>
          <div class='link-title'> <a href='#'>" + data.title + "</a></div>    
          <div class='link-description'>" + data.description + "</div>  
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  ");
},
```

UPDATE 3:

Could the posts controller be part of the issue?

This is my posts_controller.rb

```
def new
    @post = current_user.posts.new
    @post.postfiles.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html # new.html.erb
      format.json { render json: @post }
    end
  end
```

Thanks again for all your help!

Comment: any javascript errors?

Comment: @sevenseacat Nope. Firebug shows no errors.

Comment: not even after clicking the link?

Comment: @sevenseacat No errors after clicking the link. I get one javascript error, which Chrome calls "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word " and Firebug calls it "SyntaxError: unterminated string literal". It seems to be the same issue, and the errors are pointing to the sir-trevor.js file. I will include the code above. Couldn't figure out what the problem is yet. Could it have something to do, with the problem here? Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found via accident [Railscast #403 on Dynamic Forms](http://railscasts.com/episodes/403-dynamic-forms) in which nested forms were briefly part of the tutorial, too.
Ryan used in this episode an edited code for the javascript part to make the code compatible with Turbolinks. I tried the version below in my postfiles.js.coffee and it worked! The add fields link is finally generating new fields.

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .remove_fields', (event) ->
  $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
  $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
  event.preventDefault()

$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

You should watch out for singular and plural forms. The file name of your model should be **postfile.rb** instead of **postfiles.rb**

Same goes for the **_postfiles_fields.html.erb** which should be **_postfile_fields.html.erb**

So, basically the function can't find the template, because it's in plural and not singular form, but it gets called by its singular form. Change this and you should be fine. Rest of the code looks good.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! You are right, but unfortunately this is just an editing mistake, I made while I wrote the question. Sorry! In my file folders the files have the correct filenames in singular. I correct the filenames above. Sorry again!

Comment: Well, as I can't see any other problems with the code, I would try to implement the code exactly as Ryan did, with Surveys and Questions. If it still won't work compare it to his github repo: https://github.com/railscasts/196-nested-model-form-revised/tree/master/questionnaire-after

Comment: I will have a look into it, thanks! One thing: I just realized, that I am using simple form. Could this be the issue?

Comment: You should use f.input instead of f.text_field but besides that it should be fine.