# Nested model railscast 196 does not work

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, nested

I tried to follow `railscast 196` `nested model` , but I could not get it to work . The `add_link_fields` was not able to add any field to the form. I tried to use different `javascript` code. Non of them worked for me.
Here is customer Form which has several orders.

```
<%= simple_form_for @customer , :html => {:class => 'form-horizontal' }  do |f| %>
<%= f.input :first_name, :hint => 'First Name' %>
<%= f.input :last_name, :hint => 'Last Name' %>
<%= f.input :email , :hint => 'Email' %>
<%= f.input :address,  :label => false, :hint => 'Address' %>
<%= f.input :customer_number, :label => false, :hint => 'Customer Number'  %>
<%= f.input :birthday,  :label => false, :hint => 'Birthday'  %>   
</div>
      <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile">
       <div class="text-left">     
            <ul>
               <%= f.simple_fields_for :orders do |builder| %>    
              <li class = "col-lg-4">    
                  <p><%= render 'order_fields' , :f => builder %></p>    
                <li />  
                <% end %>
          <%= link_to_add_fields "Add Question", f, :orders %>
                <ul />   
            </div>
         </div>
```

Here is the `partial` ,`_order_fields`:

```
<%= f.input :order_number , :label => false , :hint => 'Number' %> 
<%= f.input :order_date, :as => :string , :label => false, :hint => 'Date' %> 
<%= f.input :sum  , :label => false , :placeholder => 'Sum', :hint => 'Sum'%>
<%= f.hidden_field :_destroy %>
```

here is my new action from `customer controller` :

```
 def new
 @customer = Customer.new
 @customer.orders.build    
 end
```

and `set_params` action is here :

```
 def customer_params
       params.require(:customer).permit(:id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :address,          :birthday, :customer_number, :orders_attributes => [:id, :order_number, :order_date, :sum, :customer_id,:quantity_of_product,:quantity,:list_of_products])
    end
```

and the `javascript` :

```
 $('form').on 'click', '.add_fields', (event) ->
        time = new Date().getTime()
        regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
        $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
        event.preventDefault()
```

and finally helper method :

```
def link_to_add_fields(name, f, association)
  new_object = f.object.send(association).klass.new
   id = new_object.object_id
   fields = f.fields_for(association, new_object, child_index: id) do |builder|
  render(association.to_s.singularize + "_fields", f: builder)
end

link_to(name, '#', class: "add_fields", data: {id: id, fields: fields.gsub("\n", "")})
end
```

And this is my `customer model` :

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :orders
    has_and_belongs_to_many :products
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders, :allow_destroy => true
end
```

I tried several other `javascript` as well, Non of them could't help me. What I am missing here? I edited this question.

Comment: By the way I got no error at all when I try to test it.And I also add here . the add_link_fields does not add any field .

Comment: you haven't told us what is not working. what's it? I see you your comment says `add_link_fields` does not add any fields. is that your problem? post your models

Comment: I remember going through the same railscast episode. the `add_link_fields` didn't work for me too. Now I remember. I opted using for another gem that does exactly that with ease. it is called cocoon. if you want to use cocoon, I can help you with that.

Comment: class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
 has_many :orders
 has_and_belongs_to_many :products
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :orders, :allow_destroy => true
    EMAIL_REGEX = /\A[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}\Z/i
    validates :first_name, :presence => true,
                         :length => { :maximum => 25 }
    validates :last_name, :presence => true,
                        :length => { :maximum => 50 }
    validates :email, :presence => true,
                    :length => { :maximum => 100 },
                    :format => EMAIL_REGEX
  
   


end

Comment: add_link_fields does not work.

Comment: If it does not work I can use that gem , let me know.

Comment: I found the gem . I will give it try later. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I went through Railscast 196 just like you and the `link_to_add_fields` helper method didn't work for me. Instead, I opted for [cocoon](https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon) which does exactly that with ease. Cocoon provides two helper methods:

`link_to_add_association` and `link_to_remove_association`

and it's got a complete example using `simple_form`, `standard rails forms` and `formtastic`

It is easier to follow the examples

Answer (score 0):

I got it to work by following YvonC's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20156830/1157812).

Pasting it here for ease:

```
$(document).on 'click', 'form .remove_fields', (event) ->
  $(this).prev('input[type=hidden]').val('1')
  $(this).closest('fieldset').hide()
  event.preventDefault()

$(document).on 'click', 'form .add_fields', (event) ->
  time = new Date().getTime()
  regexp = new RegExp($(this).data('id'), 'g')
  $(this).before($(this).data('fields').replace(regexp, time))
  event.preventDefault()
```

Answer (score 0):

I have created a repo for nesting model forms from rails cast 196/197 compatible with rails 5.

Check it at [link](https://github.com/Mtali/multiple-model-nesting)